# BootStrap DateTimePicker on dp.change fires both pickers

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, datetimepicker

I have two inputs for a start and an end date. On start 'dp.change' I'd like to set minDate of end date and on end 'dp.change' set maxDate of start date.

But the start event set both options when 'dp.change'. It set its maxDate so i can't select greater date than... now. I can't understand why.

Any help will be appreciated.

**HTML**

```
<div class="col-md-3">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label>{l s='From :' mod='everrent'}</label>
    <div class='input-group date' id='start_time'>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" />
        <span class="input-group-addon">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
        </span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-3">
  <label>{l s='To :' mod='everrent'}</label>
  <div class="form-group">
    <div class='input-group date' id='end_time'>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" />
        <span class="input-group-addon">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
        </span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  /* Initialise DateTimePickers */
  $('#start_time').datetimepicker({
    locale: 'fr',
    format: 'YYYY/MM/DD - H:mm',
    sideBySide: true,
    stepping: 5
  });
  $('#end_time').datetimepicker({
    locale: 'fr',
    format: 'YYYY/MM/DD - H:mm',
    sideBySide: true,
    stepping: 5
  });
  /* Setting up DateTimePickers */
  $('#start_time').on('dp.change', function(e) {
    $('#start_time').data("DateTimePicker").minDate(new Date());
    $('#end_time').data("DateTimePicker").minDate(e.date);
  });
  $('#end_time').on('dp.change', function(ev) {
    $('#start_time').data("DateTimePicker").maxDate(ev.date);
  });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know it's a while that this question is open, but better late than never, right?

You found this error [`#1075`](https://github.com/Eonasdan/bootstrap-datetimepicker/issues/1075) of the js library [bootstrap-datetimepicker](https://github.com/Eonasdan/bootstrap-datetimepicker). Lucky for you the solution is quite simple, when you create the second `datetimepicker` object (`#end_time`), you have to set the attribute `useCurrent` to false like this:

```
/* Initialise DateTimePickers */
  $('#start_time').datetimepicker({
    locale: 'fr',
    format: 'YYYY/MM/DD - H:mm',
    sideBySide: true,
    stepping: 5
  });
  $('#end_time').datetimepicker({
    locale: 'fr',
    format: 'YYYY/MM/DD - H:mm',
    sideBySide: true,
    stepping: 5,
    useCurrent: false //<--- this change
  });
  /* Setting up DateTimePickers */
  $('#start_time').on('dp.change', function(e) {
    $('#start_time').data("DateTimePicker").minDate(new Date());
    $('#end_time').data("DateTimePicker").minDate(e.date);
  });
  $('#end_time').on('dp.change', function(ev) {
    $('#start_time').data("DateTimePicker").maxDate(ev.date);
  });
```

See this: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/number_phi/7a4m8jh1/)

Comment: How come you used `ev` inside `$('#end_time').on('dp.change', function(ev)` and not `e`?  Shouldn't it be the same as the start time onChange function?

Comment: @PeteAdamBialecki that parameter you can call it in with any name, the important is that you provide a function with a single parameters. Eg. if you use my fiddle (from my response) you can change the parameter name 'ev' with 'myAwesomeParameter' (or simply 'e') and the script will works. I used the name 'ev' becouse I used the same snippet of code from the question.